# How to get the maximum number, from many lists in a python dictionary, by list index

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {'list_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
           'list_2': [3,4,1,0,0],
           'list_3': [1,2,3,0,6]}
```

All `list_`s in the `my_dict` have the same length (in this case `5`).

I would like, to get a `5`-length list (`final_list`), which will have as elements the `keys` of the `my_dict`, for which the element of the respective list at this position is the highest.
If there is a tie, then all keys should appear.

The output should be this: `['list_2', 'list_2', 'list_1|list_3', 'list_1', 'list_3']`

Any ideas how I can achieve that efficiently ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean by efficiently? time-efficient, space-efficient?

Comment: Also, how many elements do you have in real-life?

Comment: I have in total 5 lists, of 1k elements each list. But I need to do that for 500k dictionaries. So I am interested in time-efficient

Comment: well, try pure python, not sure vectorization would help here

Comment: @mozway what do you mean, by pure python ?

Comment: like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657022/16343464), without higher level library such as `numpy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the max element you can do:

```
tmp = [[(v, k) for v in lst] for k, lst in my_dict.items()]
t2 = map(sorted, zip(*tmp))
print([lst[-1][1] for lst in t2])
```

change the last line to account for several items having the max value.

For completeness, here is the change needed to the last line (it's relatively performant..):

```
def find_max_labels(lst):
    maxval = lst[-1][0]
    labels = []
    for val, label in reversed(lst):
        if val != maxval:
            break
        labels.append(label)
    return '|'.join(reversed(labels))

print([find_max_labels(lst) for lst in t2])
```

output:

```
['list_2', 'list_2', 'list_1|list_3', 'list_1', 'list_3']
```